# RichTextBox getting literal text

Tags: c#, forms, file, richtextbox

I'm trying to save the text from my RichTextBox to a text file. However, upon doing so, the new lines in the RTB aren't considered "new lines" and hence a `\n` isn't appended in the text file, so if I have:

`This is a test

line of content`

It will write to the text file as:

`This is a testline of content`

I'm saving the text the following way:

```
File.WriteAllText(currentFile, richTextBox1.Text);
```

I'm just wondering if there's any solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some code. Show us how you're saving the text.

Comment: Updated the OP with some code, sorry.

Comment: You could just do: `File.WriteAllLines(currentFile, richTextBox1.Lines);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(currentFile);
for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
{
    sw.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Lines[i]);
}
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

or use the rtb.SaveFile() method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use the built it `SaveFile` method instead.

```
richTextBox1.SaveFile(currentFile, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```